# Install SharePoint 2010 on Windows server 2012 OS

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, installation, windows-server-2012

How to install SharePoint 2010 on the Windows server 2012 OS.
Is this possible ?

Any step-by-step information provided by MS?

Answer (score 2):

**Possible**

[SharePoint 2010 support for Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 R2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2724471)

*MS Support reads*

> Before the release of Service Pack 2 (SP2) for Microsoft SharePoint
>   Server 2010, Microsoft did not support SharePoint Server 2010 in a
>   Windows Server 2012 or Windows Server 2012 R2 environment.
>
> However, SharePoint Server 2010 slipstream media SP2 has now been
>   released, and this configuration is supported in Windows Server 2012
>   and Windows Server 2012 R2.
>
> On Windows Server 2012 R2, Microsoft supports only the SharePoint
>   Server 2010 SP2 slipstream media configuration and not the RTM version
>   of that configuration. For full SharePoint functionality and support,
>   you must have the February 2014 cumulative update (CU) or a later CU
>   installed. Additionally, only a new SharePoint Server 2010 SP2
>   slipstream installation that has the February 2014 CU or a later CU
>   installed is supported on Windows Server 2012 R2. Microsoft does not
>   support a Windows in-place upgrade for this scenario.

**Step-by-step information provided by technet**

[How to Install and Configure Windows Server 2012 for SharePoint 2010](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12502.sharepoint-2010-how-to-install-and-configure-windows-server-2012-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Comment: Whats the meaning of slipstream media? this link   https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=39672 shows , that it supports win 2008 os only.

Comment: Could be It is not updated yet